# concatenate string in shell

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file config.ini:

```
repo_path=ssh://git@localhost:10022/root/
dir_path=/home/vagrant/workspace/
```

and a 'script.sh' to export and concatenate from that file as follow:

```
while read -r line; do export $line; done <config.ini
repo_name=$1
repo_path=$repo_path$repo_name'.git'
dir_path=$dir_path/$repo_name
echo $repo_path
echo $dir_path
```

so when i run the script:

```
./script.sh sample
```

output:

```
sample.gitlocalhost:10022/root/
/sampleagrant/workspace/
```

expected output:

```
ssh://git@localhost:10022/root/sample.git
/home/vagrant/workspace/sample
```

Comment: Well, it works as expected on my system. What shell are you using ? Are you sure it is `bash` ? Have you set the first line of your script to `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: @perror Yes it is `bash` and yes i set the first line to `#!/bin/bash`, but it didn't work as expected

Comment: `export "$line"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plausible explanation is that you have an embedded carriage return in your data.

```
sample.gitlocalhost:10022/root/
^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is to say the string is the following (using C language string literal notation):

```
"ssh://git@localhost:10022/root/\rsample.git"
```

Note the `\r` denoting a carriage return

When you send this to the terminal, the carriage return causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the line, so that `sample.git` overwrites the `ssh://...` prefix.

To debug this sort of "mysterious output" problem, you can pipe the output of the command to a binary dump utility like `od`:

```
echo $strange | od -t c  # see characters with backslash notation, or -t x1 for hex
```

Comment: Good idea, sounds feasible